# Why Google place AutocompleteService callback not getting executed?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have following code for place `AutocompleteService()` as:

```js
var strAddr = '';
if (address.value != "") {
    var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    service.getQueryPredictions({ input: address.value }, function (predictions, status) {
        console.log('1');
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            console.log('Original Response: ' + predictions[0].structured_formatting.secondary_text);
            strAddr = predictions[0].structured_formatting.secondary_text;
        }
    });
    console.log('strAddr: ' + strAddr);
    console.log('2');
}

console.log('3');
```

I am getting response in console as:

- strAddr:
- 2
- 3
- 1
- Original Response: //gettting matched address here

But it should be:

- 1
- Original Response: //matched address here>
- strAddr: //matched address here
- 2
- 3

Why the callback not executing in sequence as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getQueryPredictions` function is asynchronous (it's probably happening via AJAX).  So you can't guarantee that it will complete before the code immediately after it.

e.g. the call to getQueryPredictions might take perhaps 0.5 seconds.  So while that's happening, these two lines will be able to execute immediately:

```
console.log('strAddr: ' + strAddr);
console.log('2');
```

You can't rely on `strAddr` being available in any code that happens outside of your callback function that's waiting for the getQueryPredictions response.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that you get this

- 1
- Original Response: //matched address here>
- strAddr: //matched address here
- 2
- 3

Because this ( new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService(); ) is asynchronous call and your callback can be called at any sequence